# Adding .css in ASP.Net 5 MVC 6

Tags: css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to explore MVC6 application. I selected Framework 4.6 and Empty ASP.Net preview template. Using Visual studio 2015.

I have .css file under `wwwroot/css` directory.

And trying to use in index.cshtml as

```
<link href="../../css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

also tried

```
<link href="~/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But it's not working. Is here any technique required?

Comment: In my MVC 6 app `<link href="~/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" />` is working fine. But I have it in the _Layout.cshtml file, I think it should work.

Comment: Yes it should work, If you use the default starter web template this reference is also used in the _layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to tell ASPNET5 to use static files. In startup.cs add

`app.UseStaticFiles();`

in the Configure() function

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  @section scripts{
       <link href="~/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-file-version="true" />
    }
```

but recommended it is to add the files to the layout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would like to refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for answering questions. It is important to note your answer could be around for a long time with many different people viewing your answer and as such please try and provide the reasoning for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your files on the layout page, in MVC 6 you can specify which file you want to use for development, staging or production environment depending where you are working on.
Example:

```
<environment names="Development">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/YourStyleFile.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

Answer (score -2):

go to your App_Start Folder > BundleConfig.Cs > then find the code block that will look similar to this

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

then add the path of your css file in here

### edit 1

Now you have advised that you are using an empty preview template you have two options,

1. Add the App_start folder and add the above code block and then in your Layout.cshtml file add the line

   ```
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
   ```

or

2. in your Layout.cshtml file reference is as you would normally, but youll need it in your shared view so it carries through the rest of the site

Comment: there is no App_Start folder.

Comment: @SimonPrice OP is using Asp.Net 5, you are using a previous version. The project layout has changed significantly. There is no App_Start folder any more.